# Plotting subsetted data using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot only subsetted data, however all entries in the X axis is appearing. Subsetted for top 5% of point scorers:

Subset:

```
sub1 <- subset(dataset, points > quantile(points, prob = 1 - 5/100)) 

ggplot(sub1,aes(x=name, y=points)) +
geom_point()

name        points   club
AJ          150      rfhg
DF          300      fdfdf
RH          400      ffggffg
EW          100      gfhgfh
QA          230      kujkj
RF          220      gnhgfgf
```

There are other vectors in the original dataset - should I remove these?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Please, [edit] your question and add the output of `dput(sub1)` (or `dput(head(sub1))` if longish). Thank you.

Comment: How are you getting on with the answer below, RedEyeUser?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to operate with your data, so here's an example from base dataset `airquality`:

```
library(dplyr)

airquality %>% 
  filter(Temp > quantile(Temp, prob = 1 - 5/100)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Temp)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

As I understand, you got the same problem — no data in 7th Month, but it still exist on the x-axis. It'll be automatically removed as soon as `ggplot` understand that it's a `factor`. For example:

```
airquality %>% 
  mutate(Month = as.factor(Month)) %>%  # transform from integer to factor
  filter(Temp > quantile(Temp, prob = 1 - 5/100)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Temp)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]